# Gráfico de sazonalidade com ggplot2

Tags: ggplot2, r

Tenho um gráfico de exemplo que mostra a sazonalidade de um dado por mês ao longo dos anos. Gostaria de adaptar o gráfico para dias da semana, possuo o código de exemplo, mas não estou conseguindo adaptá-lo.

A ideia é verificar se existe sazonalidade no número de novos casos em dias da semana. Por exemplo, se há um dia ou dias que possuem mais casos confirmados e a outra hipótese é verificar se em finais de semana existe uma diminuição desse número.

Gráfico de exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código utilizado:

```
devData <- subset(df, Series=="Deviation", select=c(Series, Year, Month, Values))
meanDevData <- subset(df, Series=="Mean Deviation", select=c(Series, Year, Month, Values))
medDevData <- subset(df, Series=="Median Deviation", select=c(Series, Year, Month, Values))

ggplot(df,aes(Year,Values,colour=Series)) +
  geom_point(data=devData,size=I(2),alpha=I(0.6)) + 
  geom_line(data=meanDevData,size=I(1.5),alpha=I(0.6)) + 
  geom_line(data=medDevData,size=I(1.5),alpha=I(0.4)) + 
  theme_grey(base_size=15) +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank(), legend.position=c(.15,.9), axis.title.y=element_blank(),axis.text.x=element_blank()) + 
  ggtitle("UKRPI Additive Deviation") + facet_grid(. ~ Month) + 
  xlab(paste("Years:",min(df$Year),"to", max(df$Year)))
```

Link do site com o post: https://www.clarusft.com/exploring-seasonality-in-a-time-series-with-rs-ggplot2/

Base de dados que estou utilizando: https://covid.saude.gov.br/

Lembrando que não possuo a base de dados do exemplo para fazer testes. Se puderem ajudar, agradeço muito.

Comment: Não pode mostar a sazonalidade de dados que não a têm, o coronavirus ainda não apresenta qualquer sazonalidade porque ainda não passou tempo suficiente. Basta ver que a base começa em 2020-01-30 e acaba em 2020-04-29. Por favor reveja o que quer fazer.

Comment: A ideia é verificar se existe sazonalidade no número de novos casos em dias da semana. Por exemplo, se há um dia ou dias que possuem mais casos confirmados e a outra hipótese é verificar se em finais de semana existe uma diminuição desse número. Por isso indiquei que gostaria de colocar dias da semana em vez de meses, como no exemplo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em primeiro lugar os dados devem ser preparados, com limpeza dos `casosNovos == 0` e com funções de agregação, para calcular as médias e medianas.

A função a utilizar para ler o ficheiro é `read.csv2` uma vez que as decimais estão separadas por vírgulas.

```
df <- read.csv2("arquivo_geral_covid.csv")

df$data <- as.Date(df$data)
df$Dia <- format(df$data, format = "%u")
df$Dia <- factor(df$Dia, labels = c("seg", "ter", "qua", "qui", "sex", "sab", "dom"))
dados <- subset(df, casosNovos > 0)
dados_agg <- aggregate(casosNovos ~ Dia, dados, function(x) c(Mean = mean(x), Median = median(x)))
dados_agg <- cbind(dados_agg[1], dados_agg[[2]])
```

Agora é utilizar os dados limpos `dados` para os pontos e a base agregada `dados_agg` para as linhas horizontais. A escala do eixo dos `y` é logarítmica, para mudar isso basta comentar `scale_y_continuous`.

```
ggplot(dados, aes(data, casosNovos, group = Dia)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.3) + 
  geom_hline(data = dados_agg, 
             aes(yintercept = Mean, group = Dia),
             color = "green") + 
  geom_hline(data = dados_agg, 
             aes(yintercept = Median, group = Dia),
             color = "blue") + 
  scale_y_continuous(trans = "log10") +
  theme_grey(base_size = 15) +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank(), 
        axis.title.y = element_blank(), 
        axis.text.x = element_blank()) + 
  ggtitle("CoVID-19 - Novos casos por semana") + 
  facet_wrap( ~ Dia) + 
  xlab("Dia")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito obrigado!